# mean sqrt norm of holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let U be an open set of $\mathbb{C}$,we use the notion:$||f||_{L^2(U)}^2$={$\int_{U}$$|f|^{2}$dxdy}

(1)Let f:U$\rightarrow$$\mathbb{C}$,show that for any compact K$\subset$U,there exists a constant $C_{K}$,s.t.$sup|f(z)|$$\le$$C_{K}$$||f||_{L^2(U)}$ for z$\in$K

(2)prove that:{f is holomorphic on U:$||f||_{L^2(U)}$$\le$1} is a normal family

(3)Suppose U is a punctured disk D(0,1)-{0},if f is holomorphic on U and $||f||_{L^2(U)}$<$\infty$,prove thatz=0 is removable singularity of f

acctually,my brain is blank when i see this problem,for(1)i do not know what it means,$C_{K}$ is decided by K,thus we let it be the value.for the second one,i want to use montel theorem,but no way to prove f is uniformly bounded..for the third one,i think it will be obvious if (2) is proved

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Martin R ??actually，I just copy the problem......